# App is crashing in release mode only

Tags: ios, crash, release, debug-mode

I have searched previous questions but they did not work. I got these crash details from device logs:

> Incident Identifier: 3D66D-F1B54CC2449
>   CrashReporter Key:   4c95be7dfa542494f103b1ef
>   Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
>   Process:             Some [303]
>   Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D80AD481-A88D-4FB2-BF84-B76084B7133D/sample.app/sample
>   Identifier:          com.mytest.test
>   Version:             1.0 (1.0)
>   Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
>   Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>
> Date/Time:           2016-05-27 12:26:25.25 -0700
>   Launch Time:         2016-05-27 12:26:25.25 -0700
>   OS Version:          iOS 9.3 (13E233)
>   Report Version:      105
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
>   Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001200c9088
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>
> Filtered syslog:
>   None found
>   <
>   Dyld Error Message:
>   Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/MailApi.framework/MailApi
>     Referenced from: /var/containers/Bundle/Application/D80AD481-A88D-4FB2-BF84-B76084B7133D/sample.app/sample
>     Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
>       /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D80AD481-A88D-4FB2-BF84-B76084B7133D/sample.app/Frameworks/MailApi.framework/MailApi: mmap() errno=1 validating first page of '/private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D80AD481-A88D-4FB2-BF84-B76084B7133D/sample.app/Frameworks/MailApi.framework/MailApi'
>     Dyld Version: 390.7
>   <
>   Binary Images:
>   0x1000e8000 - 0x10032ffff sample arm64  <13340a6f4b8531ae9b451386d72bdfc6> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/D80AD481-A88D-4FB2-BF84-B76084B7133D/sample.app/sample
>   0x1200c8000 - 0x1200f7fff dyld arm64   /usr/lib/dyld

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it will help for you, got to project build phases -> Link binary with libraries -> change all library frame works status required to optional

Comment: It worked, what could be the issue? There are two framework. is it like framework using something that wont is not available? thanks

Comment: some latest updated libraries not available for some low level  OS versions.

Comment: simulator with latest os version

Comment: On device I am making release it's frequently crashing.